# systemctl running ok but status says activating

Tags: systemd

I have a simple `systemd.service` to start a qmi connection from an LTE module. It works fine and the connection is established when I start the service. My issue is that status does not inform the service has `activated` but permanently has `activating`.

This is the status:

```
● qmi_connect.service - QMI Auto Connection
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/qmi_connect.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) since Wed 2022-04-27 11:45:28 BST; 4s ago
    Process: 8030 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/Ubiquo/LTE/qmi/qmi_connect.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 8030 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 491ms
```

The service:

```
[Unit]
Description=QMI Auto Connection
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/Ubiquo/LTE/qmi/qmi_connect.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Ubiquo/LTE/qmi
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the bash script that start the qmi connection:

```
#!/bin/bash

APN="net2.vodafone.pt"
ip link set dev wwan0 down
echo Y > /sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw_ip
ip link set dev wwan0 up
qmicli --device=/dev/cdc-wdm0 --device-open-proxy --wds-start-network="ip-type=4,apn=$APN" --client-no-release-cid
udhcpc -q -f -n -i wwan0
```